# Stop page loader from dissappearing until all the angular sections have finished loading

Tags: angular

I have a page that has 2 angular sections in it and one loads before the other triggering the page loader to disappear and you are left with one section loaded and another unloaded for a few more seconds, how do I stop the page loader from disappearing until all the angular sections have been loaded?

script:

```
 <script>
    loading_screen.finish();
 </script>
```

Comment: Could you please include some of the the section code, and any attempts you've put forth toward solving this problem?

Comment: You should write an interceptor for that

Comment: @mrtig Ive tried 

//function loadFinish() {
      //  loading_screen.finish();
    //}

   // window.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
     //   $('.pg-loading-screen')
     //       .fadeOut('slow');
   // });

    //window.onload = function () {
     //   loadFinish();  //example function call.
    //}

Comment: @pixelbits how does an interceptor work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an HTTP interceptor for this. HTTP interceptors work as middleware components that you can hook into every time a request is made.  The idea is that you would increment a counter when a request is made, and decrement it when the request completes (successfully or fails).

When the counter is 0, then don't display a loader. When the counter is greater than 0, display a loader.

For the loader component itself, you could write a service that listens for changes to the counter, and use data-binding to display the spinner at the right time.

**request.interceptor.ts**

```
import { HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from "@angular/common/http";

import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally'

import { HttpMonitor } from "../request-spinner/http.monitor";

export class RequestHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private httpMonitor: HttpMonitor){

    }
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

       this.httpMonitor.addRequest();
        return next.handle(req).finally(() => {
            this.httpMonitor.removeRequest();
        })

    }
}
```

**http.monitor.ts**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
export class HttpMonitor {
    public pendingRequestNumber: number;
    public pendingRequests:Observable<number>;
    private prSubject: BehaviorSubject<number>;

    constructor() {
        this.prSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
        this.pendingRequests = this.prSubject.asObservable();
        this.pendingRequestNumber = 0;
    }

    addRequest() {
        this.prSubject.next(++this.pendingRequestNumber)
    }
    removeRequest() {
        this.prSubject.next(--this.pendingRequestNumber)
    }
}
```

**spinner.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpMonitor } from './http.monitor';

@Component({
    selector: '[spinner]',
    template: `
        <img *ngIf="httpMonitor.pendingRequestNumber >0" src="http://www.silkron.co.uk/images/spinner.gif" />
    `,
    styles: [
        `
            img {
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
            }
        `
    ]
})
export class SpinnerComponent {
    constructor(public httpMonitor:HttpMonitor){

    }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],
  declarations: [SpinnerComponent],
  exports: [],
  providers: [
    HttpMonitor,
    {
       provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
       useClass: RequestHttpInterceptor,
       multi: true,
    }, 
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule {
}
```